# learning openCV, Getting LNK2019 (unresolved external symbol)

Tags: c++, opencv, visual-studio-2017

I am currently starting to try and learn openCV and visual studio 2017 for a project at work.
I am currently following a few tutorial from openCV, however I am getting 8 LNK2019 errors.
Would you guys be able to help me with this?

I am quite new to coding in general so sorry in advance if I'm asking any stupid questions.

This is my current code:

```
#include <opencv2/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgcodecs.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    String imageName( "HappyFish.jpg" ); //by default
    if (argc > 1)
    {
        imageName = argv[1];
    }
    Mat image;

    image = imread(samples::findFile(imageName), IMREAD_COLOR); //Read the file

    if (image.empty()) //checking for valid input
    {
        cout << "Could not open or find the image" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    namedWindow("Display window", WINDOW_AUTOSIZE); //create a window for the display
    imshow("Display window", image); //showing our image inside the window
    waitKey(0); //Wait for a keystroke in the window
    return 0;
}
```

And these are my errors:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl
>   cv::fastFree(void *)" (?fastFree@cv@@YAXPAX@Z) referenced in function
>   "public: __thiscall cv::Mat::~Mat(void)" (??1Mat@cv@@QAE@XZ)  Open cv
>   test  C:\Users\BRR\source\repos\Open cv test\Open cv test\Open cv
>   test.obj  1
>
> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl
>   cv::error(int,class std::basic_string,class std::allocator > const &,char const
>   *,char const *,int)" (?error@cv@@YAXHABV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@PBD1H@Z)
>   referenced in function "public: class cv::Mat & __thiscall
>   cv::Mat::operator=(class cv::Mat &&)"
>   (??4Mat@cv@@QAEAAV01@$$QAV01@@Z)  Open cv
>   test  C:\Users\BRR\source\repos\Open cv test\Open cv test\Open cv
>   test.obj  1
>
> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall
>   cv::Mat::deallocate(void)" (?deallocate@Mat@cv@@QAEXXZ) referenced in
>   function "public: void __thiscall cv::Mat::release(void)"
>   (?release@Mat@cv@@QAEXXZ) Open cv test    C:\Users\BRR\source\repos\Open
>   cv test\Open cv test\Open cv test.obj 1
>
> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "class
>   std::basic_string,class
>   std::allocator > __cdecl cv::samples::findFile(class
>   std::basic_string,class
>   std::allocator > const &,bool,bool)"
>   (?findFile@samples@cv@@YA?AV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@ABV34@_N1@Z)
>   referenced in function _main  Open cv
>   test  C:\Users\BRR\source\repos\Open cv test\Open cv test\Open cv
>   test.obj  1
>
> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "class cv::Mat __cdecl
>   cv::imread(class std::basic_string,class std::allocator > const &,int)"
>   (?imread@cv@@YA?AVMat@1@ABV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@H@Z)
>   referenced in function _main  Open cv
>   test  C:\Users\BRR\source\repos\Open cv test\Open cv test\Open cv
>   test.obj  1
>
> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl
>   cv::namedWindow(class std::basic_string,class std::allocator > const &,int)"
>   (?namedWindow@cv@@YAXABV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@H@Z)
>   referenced in function _main  Open cv
>   test  C:\Users\BRR\source\repos\Open cv test\Open cv test\Open cv
>   test.obj  1
>
> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "int __cdecl
>   cv::waitKey(int)" (?waitKey@cv@@YAHH@Z) referenced in function
>   _main Open cv test    C:\Users\BRR\source\repos\Open cv test\Open cv test\Open cv test.obj    1
>
> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl
>   cv::imshow(class std::basic_string,class std::allocator > const &,class
>   cv::debug_build_guard::_InputArray const &)"
>   (?imshow@cv@@YAXABV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@ABV_InputArray@debug_build_guard@1@@Z)
>   referenced in function _main  Open cv
>   test  C:\Users\BRR\source\repos\Open cv test\Open cv test\Open cv
>   test.obj  1

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me this issue is normally caused by not having the linker pointed to the correct lib files. This is completed in to steps, first you need to point VS to the folder that contains the lib files, then you need to say which lib files you want.

First. 
Project >Properties. Then Configuration Properties > C/C++ >General. The in the field Additional Include Directories add the address location to the OpenCv lib folder. Mine looks like this.

OpenCV_3_3_0\build\VC17\lib\Debug

OpenCV_3_3_0\build\VC17\lib\Release

Now we need to say which libs we want. So In the VS project properties tab,
Go to Configuration Properties > Linker > Input and then Additional Dependencies field.

You will now need to add the names of the libs you want. 
opencv_calib3d330.lib is an example

All the libs are in the folder so just keep adding all the libs till the error goes away (depending on which feature you use depends on which lib you need)

[image: Lib folder for Release]

If you havent correctly built the libs for VS17 you will need to follow these instructions.

https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/introduction/windows_install/windows_install.html#windows-installation

Comment: Is there a place where I can find a list of these libs? And what Folder are you refering to at the end of your answer?

Comment: Hey Bartrae, 

I cant point to the folder, because it depends on your own path names. 

But its the lib folder in the build section of your opencv. I can help further if you show the folder structure of your opencv build. 

As for a list, the folder contains all the files, so that is the list, keep adding the files till there is no more error (Not a great answer but the files change depending on the features you use)

Comment: I added a picture in my answer

Comment: If i understand correctly, you mean a path like this "C:\lib\Build\opencv\lib" right?, in there I've got two folders , "Debug" and "Release". There are a three .lib files in those folders.

Comment: Yes those folders, and you need to add the two different addresses depending if your build is Debug or Release. 

There is only three? What are they?

Comment: "ade.lib", "opencv_img_hash430d.lib" and "opencv_world430d.lib"

Comment: I guess three options here, 

Option 1
Follow my instructions above with just the three lib files. 

Option 2
File search the whole opencv folder for more lib files. 

Option 3
Check that your opencv for VS studio correctly built.

Comment: When I add the three lib files (option 1), I get a new error: "LNK1104 cannot open file ade.lib". when I do option 2 I find a few more .lib files in a folder with path: "C:\lib\Build\opencv\3rdparty\lib\Release" but these are completely different from the ones in your picture. I gues only option 3 is left, would you know where i can find a guide to check if my opencv did build correctly?

Comment: Looks like you only need opencv_world.lib with the new 4v of openCV

Comment: Chris, thanks you for your help. I've done a complete reinstall of both openCV and visual studio (I'm now on 2019). It seems to be working for now. Thank you for investing your time in my problem.

Comment: Not a problem, Did you setup the linkers and lib files, or did the installers do it for you?

Comment: I still needed tu setup the linker files, this time only the opencv_world430d.lib was enough though.

Comment: Awesome, glad i was of some help to you

Answer (score 0):

It seems you did not include the necessary dependencies:
You should follow: https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/introduction/windows_visual_studio_Opencv/windows_visual_studio_Opencv.html

It's explained in great detail there. Search for: "Additional Dependencies", but you should probably re-evaluate the other steps you've made to set up the project.

Comment: Thank you, I will look at this an will come back to you.

Comment: I've looked at the guide, a few things are a bit different since they appear to be using a different visual studio version. however when I get to the point where a need to add a load of .lib files in Project >Properties>Linker>Input I seem to be encountering a problem. It seems I've only got 3 .lib files in the lib folder (see the discussion with Chris)

Comment: Ok, so you're using a newer version: but you can find a tutorial for that as well: https://medium.com/@subwaymatch/opencv-410-with-vs-2019-3d0bc0c81d96 Just add opencv_world. But it's the same thing, only change is that the libraries have been grouped into one binary

Comment: would you recommend doing a complete reinstall of OpenCV following the guide you linked in stead of trying to salvage what I've got? Again, I'm quite new to this sorry if I'm asking dumb questions.

Comment: It's up to you :) It's probably salvageable, but I would usually start from scratch.

Comment: I'll wait until tomorrow morning if more suggestions come in. if non of those work I'll probably do a complete reinstall tomorrow (my shift end in 30 minutes), would i be wise to upgrade visual studio to 2019 as well?

Comment: Up to you. You could use it just as well with either. Personally I prefer mingw, cmake and maybe eclipse as an ide, but if you use windows forms then vs is the way to go.

Comment: Nicolae Natea, thank your for your help I've done a complete reinstall and it seems to be working for now. I haven't got any errors and I get the picture of the "happy fish". Thank you for investing your time in my problem